# Set default value for select input in php

Tags: php

I want to set the default value at "-24hours". All options are dynamically generated with a foreach.

```
<select id="search3" name="date" onchange='this.form.submit();'>
    <?php
        $orderby_options3 = array(
            '-3day' => 'Last 3 days',
            '-48hours' => '48 hours',
            '-24hours' => '24 hours',
        );
        foreach( $orderby_options3 as $value3 => $label3 ) {
            echo "<option ".selected( $_GET['date'], $value3 )." value='$value3'>$label3</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

I know that I should add "selected" parameter for the option but in my case, it's not possible.

Comment: Can we see the function "selected" please

Comment: I don't have one

Comment: So what is this line about? `selected( $_GET['date'], $value3 )`

Comment: Yes it is possible, you just need to check for the condition that matches your requirements.

Comment: Ok, I took the function from the internet. I am going to check this function

Comment: @user1708580 try my answer if you're using php7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always want -24hours to be selected and this page won't be used as an edit page, then you can do something like this:

```
<select id="search3" name="date" onchange='this.form.submit();'>
<?php
    $orderby_options3 = array(
        '-3day' => 'Last 3 days',
        '-48hours' => '48 hours',
        '-24hours' => '24 hours',
    );

    foreach( $orderby_options3 as $value3 => $label3 ) {
        $select = ($value3 == '-24hours') ? "selected='selected'":""; // see this line
        echo "<option ".selected( $_GET['date'], $value3 )." value='$value3' $select>$label3</option>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<select id="search3" name="date" onchange='this.form.submit();'>
    <?php
        $orderby_options3 = array(
            '-3day' => 'Last 3 days',
            '-48hours' => '48 hours',
            '-24hours' => '24 hours',
        );
        foreach( $orderby_options3 as $value3 => $label3 ) {
            $selected = in_array($value3, [$_GET['date'] ?? null, '-24hours']) ? 'selected' : '';
            echo "<option $selected value='$value3'>$label3</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

[click to see the demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8d610b320699b0c4c820a0b1326f46a178647d9c)